# Text search in Mongodb is not working

Tags: mongodb, text, indexing

I'm interested in getting the text search for the database and I have done the following and it is still not working.

**1**. I have created a index on collection on a particular field.

`Db.data1.ensureIndex({title:"text"})` - Works good.

**2**. Also updated the configuration file with the below `php.ini`

`setParameter=textSearchEnabled=true`

**3**. Did a search on the database with the below query and getting the error message:

`db.data1.runCommand("text",{title:"Arvind"})
Errmsg: "no such cmd:text"
bad cmd: { "text" : "data1","title":"Arvind"}
"ok":0`

Could you please help on getting this issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you have enabled text search or that any of your commands have worked.

- You need to enable text search in the [mongod startup](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.textSearchEnabled). Alternately there is a `db.runCommand` for that can be invoked from the "admin" database. This is **not** a setting for PHP ini.
- Then you can run `db.collection.ensureIndex({ "field": "text" })` where "field" is the field on which you wish to enable the text index. It seems you may have done this in PHP code and ignored the error. Please note you may only have **one** text index on a collection.

The correct form of running a Text search is then using:

```js
db.collection.runCommand("text", { "search": "phrase" })
```

So regardless of "which" field you have indexed the argument is always passed to the "search" parameter.

Also note that you **must** have a mongodb server version 2.4 and above in order for this to work. For more information see the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/search-for-text/).

Comment: Tried DB.data1.runCommand("text",{"search":"Arvind"}) . but still getting the same error

Comment: From the documentation: "Since  version 2.6: MongoDB enables the text search feature by default". So you don't need to enable text search if you are using a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, [MongoDB 2.6 deprecated the text command](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/command/text/) and according to my observations removed the text command in 3.0, even though [the release notes make no mention of it](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0/).

Use the `$text` command instead.

Update: The [compatibility changes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/) documentation does, however, indicate that the command was removed.